# Prevent HTML escaping in form text field?

Tags: python, html, forms, text, html-escape-characters

When I paste HTML into a form text field, it is escaped once the form is submitted. Is there a way to have the HTML as output rather than escaped text? I'm using Python to process the form.

Comment: post your code to check what you do

Comment: Do you mean just the HTML field code?

Comment: Both, the code of the html input, how you send(form, javascript) and python read input from html

Comment: That's a ton of code on the Python side so what specifically are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at converting the escaped string back to HTML content. If the form data is URL escaped, you can use `urllib.unquote_plus()` on Python 2.x or `urllib.parse.unquote_plus()` in Python 3.x.

Check out [this blog post](https://www.urldecoder.io/python/) on details of implementation and usage.